# Is Hibernate query.uniqueResult() hit data base

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have use below code to get interger value.

```
Query query = currentSession().getNamedQuery("getUser");
query.setString("password", password);
query.setString("userId", userId);

if (query.uniqueResult() != null && (Integer) query.uniqueResult() = 1 ) {
 ...
}
```

Please explain how

```
query.uniqueResult()
```

work with cache and with out cache

Is this hit database twice ?

What happen if we enable cache ? even its hit twice data base ?

Comment: `getUser` is a strange name to getting an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

yes it does. you should store the value in a variable and check if the variable is null/1

Comment: sadly not. i learned it by using it and looking when and how often my querys hit the db

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work. 
Yes it will hit de DB twice.

You might follow XtremeBaumer advise AND make your tes like this :

```
Integer test = query.uniqueResult();     
if ( test != null && test == 1 ) {
 ...
}
```